# Groovy in jenkins - curl to Github Api

Tags: jenkins, curl, groovy, github-api, jenkins-groovy

Trying to send a request to GitHub API from Groovy:

```
def res = null

withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'my-github-token', variable: 'GITAPITOKEN')]) {
    withEnv(["REPO=${repo}", "PRID=${prId}", "LABEL=${label}"]) {
        res = sh (script: 'curl -X PUT -H \\"Authorization: token $GITAPITOKEN\\" -d \\"{\\\\"labels\\\\":[\\\\"$LABEL\\\\"]}\\" https://api.github.com/repos/my-user/$REPO/issues/$PRID/labels', returnStdout: true).trim()
    }
}

println("${res}")
```

it shows that it executes the following:

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: token ****" -d "{\"labels\":[\"my-label\"]}" https://api.github.com/repos/my-user/my-repo/issues/1/labels
```

When I run this command locally (including all the escaped characters) it works perfectly

But on jenkins - this returns

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: token

curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ****"

curl: (3) unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position:

my-label\"]}"

          ^
```

and:

```
{

"message": "Not Found",

"documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/issues#set-labels-for-an-issue"

}
```

So it seems the header escape is somehow not working - what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def repo = 'test'
                    def label = "-d \"{\"labels\":[\"label1\"]}"
                    def prId = "123"
                    def token = "1234567890"
                    withEnv(["REPO=${repo}", "PRID=${prId}", "LABEL=${label}", "GITAPITOKEN=${token}"]) {
                        res = sh (script: 'curl -v -X PUT -H \"Authorization: token $GITAPITOKEN\" $LABEL https://api.github.com/repos/my-user/$REPO/issues/$PRID/labels', returnStdout: true).trim()
                        echo "$res"
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the escaped quotes and what it was actually printing were 2 completely different things